# Getting a value from another frame javascript change a DropDown to input

Tags: javascript, php, html, frames

I'm new to php and I'm trying to pass the value from one frame to another frame. Wanted I change the following code in this form, have one input and one button, and when I press the button on input value that will for the other frame (frame1). But I'm not able to change how I want.

framset.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frames Example</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="*,400" frameborder="YES" border="2" framespacing="0">
<frame src="frame1.html" name="frame1">
<frame src="frame2.html" name="frame2" scrolling="NO" noresize>
</frameset>
</html>
```

frame1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frame 1</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function SetSelectedValue()
{
    var selectedIndex = document.frmDropDown.lstTest.selectedIndex;
    var selectedValue = document.frmDropDown.lstTest[selectedIndex].value;
    window.parent.frame2.frmSubmit.txtTest.value = selectedValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Frame 1</h1>
<form name="frmDropDown">
<select name="lstTest" onchange="SetSelectedValue();">
    <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

fram2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frame 2</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedValue()
{
    var selectedValue = window.parent.frame1.lstTest.value;
    alert("Selected Value is \'" + selectedValue + "\'");
    document.frmSubmit.txtTest.value = selectedValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="GetSelectedValue();">
<form name="frmSubmit">
    <input type="text" name="txtTest">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: man, try to look at the point of php, you don't need the frames - they're not even needed in html since we have iframes ;)

Comment: But i need for my website, i need diferents frames...

Comment: and are you really using php ? I see only javascript ..if you're using php, you can use include function of php, which will insert frame1.php into index.php (which has frameset)

Comment: oh I was wrong, is not php but javascript. why this not work this way:       <input id="lat" type="text" value="40">
      <input type="button" name="button" value="How" onchange="SetSelectedValue()"><br>

Comment: Have you checked your browser’s error console?

Comment: I put the code does not give error, works fine, but i dont want to DropDown but i want the input and the button

Comment: So your only problem here is switching out the select field for a text input, and then grab the value of that input …? Well, you obviously know how _write_ access to an input field’s value works, and _read_ access uses the very same attribute …

Comment: Can you write a example please